# Java Bound mismatch error but I extended Comparable interface

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a binary tree which has heaps as nodes. But I couldn't figure out why this error shows up.

First, these are the classes:

BinaryTree:

```
public class MyBinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Serializable{...}
```

Heap:

```
public class MyHeap<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<E>{...}
```

ValueOccurance:

```
public class ValueOccurance<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<E> {

    private E data;
    private int occur;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(E o) {
        return data.compareTo(o);
    }
}
```

So , here is the problem: In main I can't create x and y.

```
MyHeap<ValueOccurance<Integer>> x = new MyHeap<>();
MyBinarySearchTree<ValueOccurance<Integer>> y = new MyBinarySearchTree<>();
```

Can you please tell me where is my fault and a little explanation too?

Regards.

Comment: `ValueOccurance<E>` is `Comparable<E>` not `Comparable<ValueOcurrence<E>>`. i.e. it cannot compare instances of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyHeap` and `ValueOccurence` need to be comparable to instances of themselves, not instances of `E`.

Note the differences between the following and your code (highlighted below):

```
public static class MyBinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Serializable{  };

public static class MyHeap<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<MyHeap<E>>{  
                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^
    public int compareTo(MyHeap<E> other) {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class ValueOccurance<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<ValueOccurance<E>> {
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    private E data;
    private int occur;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ValueOccurance<E> o) {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return data.compareTo(o.data);
                              ^^^^^^
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    MyHeap<ValueOccurance<Integer>> x = new MyHeap<>();
    MyBinarySearchTree<ValueOccurance<Integer>> y = new MyBinarySearchTree<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ValueOccurance<E>` is `Comparable<E>`, not `Comparable<ValueOcurrence<E>>`. i.e. it cannot compare instances of itself.

Comment: Same problem with `MyHeap` -- should `implement Comparable<MyHeap<E>>`